# Why is there extra space after assigning a background color to my tab header templates?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to change the default background color of the tabs in our WPF application to make them more visible to our users.

In our tabs we have grids that contain a descriptive image and text to define what kind of information is in the tabs. I've attempted to create a template with some really out there colors for testing purposes to make them very visible. Right now they look like this: [Image of tabs with ugly borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAeee.png)

Here's the style definition I'm using for now, based on a different StackOverflow post I found:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border x:Name="grid" Background="Red">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </Border>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}},Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="grid" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here's an example of a header as defined in a table item:

```
<TabItem.Header>
       <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Width="25" Source="{converters:FontToImage Text=&#xf05a;, FontFamily=../../Resources/Fonts/#FontAwesome}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12" Foreground="Black" Grid.Column="1">
                <AccessText Text="Record Info"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem.Header>
```

I'm just trying to figure out how to get the entire header filled in the the colors as defined in the style.

Comment: You're just changing the background of the content portion of the tab item header, not the whole control. You can set the `Background` attribute of individual TabItems, or set Background via a TabItem Style, but the background color is overriden by triggers in the control template on mouseover and for the selected tab item. If you want to change those too, you'll have to go into "Design" mode in VS for this XAML file, right click on a TabItem header, and select "Edit Template" | "Edit A Copy". Once you've got that, you can alter the triggers.

Comment: I only want the header to change, not the entire tab item.

Comment: I gave you an answer that does precisely what you want. I can't make you try it. Good luck.

Comment: Your comment appears to suggest I'd be changing the entire tabitem. This is not what I want. Also, FWIW, "Edit a Copy" is greyed out in my visual studio so I can't seem to try it anyway. I'm currently investigating that.